# How to change the "Map server" for the Map component in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, wms

I used map component in *iReport*. As a default behavior it gets map from google

Is it possible to change map server url? (For example, geoserver, bing, or openstreet server can be used for that)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for image expression java.net.Url shuold be used and the source will be the request like below

```
<image>
 <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="40"/>
 <imageExpression class="java.net.Url">
  <![CDATA["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=topp%3Astates&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=-14.15104058007,21.731919794922,-57.154894212888,58.961058642578&&width=780&height=330&format=image%2Fpng"]]>
 </imageExpression>
</image>
```